# docker-compose not restarting correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have the following docker-compose.yml
The restart of the mediawiki_db container is working.
The problem is, that the mediawiki container will not restart after reboot besides the fact that it also has the restart: always policy.

```
# MediaWiki with MariaDB
#
# Access via "http://localhost:8080"
#   (or "http://$(docker-machine ip):8080" if using docker-machine)
version: '2'
services:
  mediawiki_db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    container_name: mediawiki_db
    volumes:
      - ~/wiki/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      # @see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/includes/DefaultSettings.php
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_wiki'
      MYSQL_USER: 'wikiuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pw'
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: always
    container_name: mediawiki
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ~/wiki/var/www/html/images:/var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
    depends_on:
      - mediawiki_db
```

What is it i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [MediaWiki](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-docker/blob/4f836fabe384623b9a6d9e43a5d025c267bfe496/stable/Dockerfile) DockerFile, there is no `CMD` being run when you start up the container.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the `restart: always` can only work if there is a command that docker-compose is monitoring. And therefore restart the container with.

Comment: do you see another way to solve my problem of manually having to restart the containers after every reboot?

Comment: Im not familiar with MediaWiki, but you could always add a `command: <start my process here>` to the docker-compose file. Forinstance if you had a python script in a container you would run `command: python3 run.py`

Comment: I stand corrected. The php 7.1 image they extend (https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/511db0eb59337abf2b105e83ce0f0f1401dbe68f/7.1/apache/Dockerfile) has a command.  Can you try running the compose file with `command: apache2-foreground`

Comment: i added ```command: apache2-foreground``` to the mediawiki container but without success. hmm

Comment: When you run `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker ps -a` what is the command of the mediawiki container?

Comment: ```docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground``` and for mediawiki_db ```docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld```

Comment: And if you put `docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground` as the command, still nothing?